# How can I query for the first matching related records?

Tags: soql

Given a list of master record Ids, I would like to get the *first* related child record for each master record.  Assume that I can't control the initial inputs to simply include the child records in the first place. Is there a way to do this in a single SOQL query?

(This is, in essence, the bulkified version of this question: [get First contact showed in a related list](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/15789/get-first-contact-showed-in-a-related-list))

Here are the options I already know about:

### 1) Sub-query on the parent object:

```
List<Id> masterIds = fromSomewhereElse();

// Re-query for the masters, including the first matching child
List<Master__c> masters = [
    SELECT Id, 
        (SELECT Id, Master__c, LastModifiedDate 
         FROM Children__r
         ORDER BY LastModifiedDate DESC
         LIMIT 1)
    FROM Master__c
    WHERE Id IN :masterIds];

// Iterate through and extract the children
// Yes - this is contrived; doing it for the sake of the example
List<Child__c> children = new List<Child__c>();
for (Master__c master : masters) {
    if (!master.Children__r.isEmpty()) {
       children.add(master.Children__r.get(0));
    }
}
```

Pro: Easy to get just one child record for each parent record.

Con: You have to re-query for the master records, which counts as one extra SOQL query plus twice as many rows returned.

### 2) Query for all child objects, and then choose first to keep

```
List<Id> masterIds = fromSomewhereElse();

// Query for all of the masters' child records
List<Child__c> allChildren = [
    SELECT Id, Master__c, LastModifiedDate
    FROM Child__c
    WHERE Master__c IN :masterIds
    ORDER BY Master__c DESC, LastModifiedDate DESC];

// Iterate through and save the first child for each master
List<Child__c> children = new List<Child__c>();
Id currentMasterId;
for (Child__c child : allChildren) {
    if (child.Master__c != currentMasterId) {
       currentMasterId = child.Master__c;
       children.add(child);
    }
}
```

Pro: Counts as a single SOQL query
Con: There are potentially LOTS of extra rows queried, and the time to check the limit in Apex.

### What I'd Like

Either a syntax for doing this without the extra query or extra rows, or insights into how to choose which of these approaches makes sense in a given context.

Answer (score 3):

You may be able to utilize [GROUP BY](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/soql_sosl/Content/sforce_api_calls_soql_select_groupby.htm) to do this. Something like:

```
SELECT
    Master__c, MAX(LastModifiedDate)
FROM
    Child__c
WHERE
    Master__c IN :masterIds
ORDER BY
    Master__c DESC, LastModifiedDate DESC
GROUP BY
    Master__c
```

This will only return a single record per Master__c object. The only issue you may have is that you need to utilize [aggregate functions](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/soql_sosl/Content/sforce_api_calls_soql_select_agg_functions.htm) which may cause you some issues depending on what data you want.

To give an example, I ran this query in my test org. My test org has 3 accounts with `BillingState` set to `CA`:

```
SELECT
    BillingState
FROM 
    Account
WHERE
    BillingState = 'CA'
GROUP BY
    BillingState
```

When this query is run, it only returns a single record since it grouped the results together into a single record. I did not need to use an aggregate function on BillingState because it was part of the `GROUP BY`. If it was not part of the `GROUP BY`, I would need to use an aggregate function on it. However, I wouldn't be able to pull out the Id of the account, because technically it is an aggregate of all 3 accounts. There is no aggregate function to get only a single `Id` from it.

If you need the `Id`s for your records, your first approach is best in my opinion.

Answer (score 0):

You can accomplish this using a combination of FOR loops and SOQL query for parent to child relationships.   Salesforce servers only count this as one SOQL Query, but requires you run 2 FOR loops to iterate through the child query results.

```
for(ParentObject__c parent :  [SELECT Id, (SELECT Id, Custom_Date__c from Children__r 
                                          ORDER BY Custom_Date__c DESC //descending order will yield most recent record...
                                          LIMIT 1
                                         )
                              FROM ParentObject__c
                              WHERE Id =: parentIds]) {

    //loop through child results and add result to List for further use in code
        for(Child__c child : parent.Children__r){

        myList.add(child);            
        //system.debug(child);


    }



}
```

Link to example from SFDC (very last example on page):

https://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/langCon_apex_loops_for_SOQL.htm